# How to prevent Vue.js from automatically merging CSS classes?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I recently started working with Vue.js and I really enjoy it but I have come across something that I just can't figure out how to do. I have searched and read the documentation but found no solution.

When you add a CSS class to any of your components Vue.js will automatically add or merge the CSS classes with the root element in your child component.

This is a nice feature but I need to deactivate this feature for a specific component since I want the classes to be added to a child element of the root element.

I made this fiddle to illustrate http://jsfiddle.net/rasmuswoelk/9m2j0a9s/3

```
<div id="demo">
  <child-component class="some-class"></child-component>
</div>
```

(The "some-class" is being added automatically and adds a green background color)

How can I prevent Vue.js from automatically merging CSS classes?

Comment: Are you looking for [scoped-css](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/scoped-css.html).

Comment: So you want to get `<div class="child"><h1 class="some-class">Hello</h1></div>`?

Comment: @Saurabh Nope - it's not related to scoped css.

Comment: @str Yeah, basically. There must be a non-hacky way of achieving this.

Comment: Than why dont you have this inside template only: `<h1 class="some-class">Hello</h1>`

Comment: @Saurabh I need to be able to have a wrapping div that doesn't receive any CSS classes and then a child element (input) that get the CSS classes getting passed.

Comment: replace the template line with this 
template: `<div><h1 class="child">Hello</h1></div>`

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem to me. Vue correctly merges the classes because the `<child-component>` tag is literally replaced with that component's template's root element, which itself may have classes. You can't prevent Vue from doing this. Could you explain in a bit more detail how you want your component to work? You said you want the class to be added to a child element of the root element, then why not make a prop (say, "customClass") which you can then bind to the class of the specific child component you want, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9m2j0a9s/5/)?

Comment: @DecadeMoon I'm building a UI framework for a company and the idea is that later on a lot of developers will use this system. So to keep it clean I wanted to use the normal prop-names for things such as CSS classes. I could do "customClass" of course but it would be more intuitive to just add the "class"-prop to the element.

In this case I wan't to make an input-component which has a wrapper with relative positioning so I can add icon, popover or similar.

In React I would have to manually merge the props so in that sense Vue.js is better when it comes these kind of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**
I disagree that it is intuitive to have a class that is applied to a component be moved by that component to an inner element, so my recommendation is still: Pass it as a prop.

However, it is possible to do what you want to do, with some caveats. The component will have a list of classes that belong on the outer element. In `mounted`, it looks at `$el.classList` and finds the classes that are not among the known outer element classes. Those get applied to the inner element and removed from the outer element. Caveat: if one of the outer element classes is applied to the component, it will not be moved to the inner element. And any updates to the applied class will not be caught.

```js
Vue.component('child-component', {
  template: `<div :class="outerClasses"><h1 :class="childClasses">Hello</h1></div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      outerClasses: ['child'],
      childClasses: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.childClasses = Array.from(this.$el.classList).filter((c) => !this.outerClasses.includes(c));
    for (const c of this.childClasses) this.$el.classList.remove(c);
  }
});

var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo'
});
```

```css
.child {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.some-class {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="//vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <child-component class="some-class a b c"></child-component>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup of course. But the idea was to use the normal way of passing props so it's more intuitive for other developers using the components.

Comment: Alright, so it is possible. But I guess it will be a lot less hacky if I just pass it as a prop. I will mark your answer as the correct since it actually solves what I was looking for - even though I was hoping there would be a simpler way :-)

Answer (score 1):

A more simpler way (imo) is to bind the incoming class attribute and dynamic class prop to the data and remove them from the vnode (virtual node) during the `created()` hook.

```js
Vue.component('child-component', {
  template: `
    <div class="child">
      <h1 :class="staticClass">Hello</h1>
    </div>
  `,
  
  data() {
    return {
      staticClass: [],
    }
  },

  created() {
    // dynamic :class prop
    this.staticClass.push(this.$vnode.data.class)
    // delete if not applying on this.$el
    delete this.$vnode.data.class
    
    // static class attr
    this.staticClass.push(this.$vnode.data.staticClass)
    // delete if not applying on this.$el
    delete this.$vnode.data.staticClass
  },
});

var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',

  data: {
    dynamicClass: 'dynamic-class'
  },
});
```

```css
.child {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.some-class {
  background-color: green;
}

.dynamic-class {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo">
  <child-component :class="dynamicClass" class="some-class"></child-component>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will want to wrap the whole thing in another `<div></div>` as Vue will merge the classes on the top element. If you just want the style for `<h1>` then try doing this:

```
template: `<div><h1 class="child">Hello</h1></div>`
```

This should give you the expected behavior, let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah but it has to be dynamic classes. So if I make a component e.g. `<form-input class="input-big" />` it will add the class to the wrapper element automatically where as I need it to be passed to the actual input inside the component so it will modify that and not the wrap: `<div class="input-wrap-for-doing-stuff"><input type="text" /><icon name="search"></div>`.

If that makes sense. The wrap is really just for positioning icons, tooltips etc.

Comment: then don't call it class and call it at child-class and pass it down as props, then vue will not merge it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't abstract away the wrapper div that you have in your template, and trying to make the component work in such as way as though that div doesn't exist will only lead to confusion and incorrect styling.

Let's say that you managed to get your component to apply the outer `class` to a nested element in its template (which is what you want). Now when people use that component and apply a class to it, the style is applied to the input element and it is as though the whole component consists solely of the input element and there is no such wrapper div (this is the behavior you want).

The problem with this is that some styles will work (like `background-color`, or any appearance style), but other styles that affect the layout won't work (like `position: absolute`, because it will cause the input element to be positioned relative to the wrapper div which is not what was expected).

People who use that component should know about how the template is structured so they can style it correctly, because in reality there *is* a wrapper div there which they need to take into account.

I should mention you might be able to abstract away the wrapper div by using web components or the shadow DOM, but that's out of context of Vue.